# Return multiple values from a computed filter in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a search box where when the user inputs an artist name and it shows a list of artists that match the user input.

I want to display the artist image next to the artist name in the search.

I have an object that contains the following. Artist Name as key and path to image as value

```
Radiohead: 'path_to_image',
Elliott Smith:'path_to_image'
```

I have a computed property that filters the artists name for search.

```
computed: {
filteredArtists() {
  return Object.keys(this.artistsList).filter((artist) => {
    return artist.match(this.artistName)
  }) 
}
```

},

and in my template I'm iterating throgh the values

```
<ul class="searchFliter" v-for="artist in filteredArtists">
  <li v-text="artist"></li>
</ul>
```

I can't find a way to manage that with computed values. I can easily iterate over my object and display both Artist name and Artist image but can't filter it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to stick to your data structure then there are a number of ways you could manage to display the image along with the matching artists. Since you are essentially getting a list of keys to your `artistList` object in your computed property, you can use that key to get the path using `artistList[artist]`.

```
<ul class="searchFliter" v-for="artist in filteredArtists">
  <li>{{artist}} <img :src="artistList[artist]"></li>
</ul>
```

However, if you want to instead, as you suggest in the title of your post, return multiple values from the list, then you can alter the computed property.

```
filteredArtists() {
  let matches = return Object.keys(this.artistsList).filter((artist) => {
    return artist.match(this.artistName)
  }) 

  return matches.map(m => ({name: m, imagePath: this.artistsList[m]}))
}
```

Here the computed property is finding all the matches and then creating a new object containing the name and image path. Use it in the template like so:

```
<ul class="searchFliter" v-for="artist in filteredArtists">
  <li>{{artist.name}} <img :src="artist.imagePath"></li>
</ul>
```

Of course, you can also choose a different data structure as well. Why not use use an array of artist objects?

```
[
  {name: "Radiohead", imagePath: "path to image"},
  {name: "Elliott Smith", imagePath: "path to image"}
]
```

In which case your computed property simply becomes

```
filteredArtists() {
  return this.artistsList.filter(m => m.name.match(this.artistName))
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly.  Thanks a lot. I have another question, why this doesn't work if I display the text using v-text inside the <li>

Comment: @QaisAbouJaoudé How are you trying to display it? v-text = what?

Comment: v-text="artist"

Comment: @QaisAbouJaoudé In all of the options in the answer, `artist` is an object and you would need to use the properties with `v-text`, as in `v-text="artist.name"`. But I can't think of a reason why you would ever use `v-text`.

Comment: aha. thank you. I'm new to Vue.js so I'm not sure whats the best to use. But i found using v-text to be cleaner than putting things between the html tags